# Rails nested form for belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms

I'm new to Rails and have some troubles with creating a nested form.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Now I would like to create a new company from the user sign_up page (I use Devise, BTW) by given only a company name. And have a relation between the new User and new Company.

In the console I can create a company for an existing user like this:

```
@company = User.first.build_company(:name => "name of company")
@company.save
```

That works, but I can't make this happen for a new user.  In my new user sign_up form I tried this (I know its wrong by creating a new User first but I'm trying to get something working here.)

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' }, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="inputs">
  <% 
    @user = User.new
    company = @user.build_company()

  %>
  <% f.fields_for company  do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.input :name, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
  <% end %>      

  <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary', :value => 'Sign up' %>
</div>
```

I did my best to Google for a solution/ example.  I found some nested 
form examples but it's just not clear to me how to do this.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I didn't get an error, just no 'company name' text field in the form..

Answer (score 4):

If you using Devise - I guess in user model you have:

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

So, if it's true - I think this may help:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :reject_if => :all_blank
  ...
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :company_attributes
end
```

Form:

```
<% resource.build_company %>
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="inputs">
  <%= f.fields_for :company  do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.input :name, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
  <% end %>      

  <%= f.input :email, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary', :value => 'Sign up' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for you answer, it makes sense to me but it's not working yet...

So in the form resource is the user object and we try to build a company relation, and the attr_accessible :company_attributes allows al the company field to be accesible from the user form.

So i have used your code for my model and form but the form doesn't show the company 'name' field and in my seed.rb i try to set :company_id for the seed user and i get an error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: company_id

any ideas on what goed wrong? Thx!

Comment: I've added :company_id to attr_accessible in my User model, now the seed works. But the form is not showing my company name field. I don't get any errors and when i do <%= debug(resource) %> i see only the user model attributes. I really don't know where to look for now..

Comment: I make a mistake, just use "<%=" with fields_for.

Comment: That was it! Thank for your help, really appreciated it. Greets Daniel